# Don't know what I'm doing wrong in my Unit Test

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I have a Unit Test for my LoginSystem, and it's failing and I have no idea why, In my opinion I think my code is correct, it seemed to be working for the past couple of weeks and I only found this error through Unit Testing.

```
public bool matchCheck(string Username, string Password)
        {
            //create a new bool and set it to false.
            bool returnvar = false;

            //for each basemember in the list of members.
            foreach (BaseMember bm in hillracing.Members)
            {
                //if the username is equal to a list item username AND the password is also equal.
                if (Username == bm.userName && Password == bm.passWord)
                {
                    //they exist within the same object, so return true.
                    returnvar = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new Exception(" Did not match!");
                }
            }

            //return this bool, true or false.
            return returnvar;
        }
```

Can someone tell me why my exception is always thrown? thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're comparing ONE username and password to an entire collection of usernames and passwords. By definition, only one item in the entire collection should evaluate to `true` and the rest should evaluate as `false`. In your case, you're throwing an exception the very first time one evaluates to `false`.

Comment: Fixed it, sorry, I was being stupid, EACH TIME it looped around it would throw the exception if it didn't find it (it's obviously NOT going to find the matching set EVERY time so it had a 100% probability to throw the exception) In other words, It's ONLY going to find the matching Dataset it's looking for 1:100 times and this code would make it throw the exception on the very FIRST unsuccessful match, regardless or not if the dataset was actually found.

Answer (score 0):

On a side note, comments like this one:

//create a new bool and set it to false.

bool returnvar = false;

Should be avoided since the code talks for itself. Useless comments dont add any value to the code but rather have a negative effect.

Comment: I know as well as anyone that the code comments are very obvious, I'm making the comments for people that doesn't understand code AT ALL, if it was up to me I wouldn't have this level of comments in my program.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to improve the routine, then consider returning true when a match is found, if it gets to the end of the loop, return false or throw an exception. My personal preference is to avoid throwing exceptions unless it is actually an exception.

Comment: "If you are looking to improve the routine, then consider returning true when a match is found" 

Isn't that what I do? I like throwing exceptions because It makes me HAVE to validate them correctly in my code, but I agree, there are situations where they aren't needed.